# Need to define control flow and functionalities

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a project with requirements as below,

1. Login form opens up and asks for user name and password.
2. Login Successful - Login form closes and another main form opens and all the functionalities will be added here.
3. In the main form there is a Call button when clicked on it, it will pop a dial pad.
4. When the number is entered on the dial pad and clicked "ok", control comes back to the same main form.
5. When logout is clicked, It wil take me to the login screen again.

For this can anybody explain me the following points:

1. How do I tranfer the control from one form to another?
2. I have to make sure when user clicks on the close 'x' , I have to log out and close the windows?
3. Neeed some rough class information.

Thanks in advance.

This is what i used earlier to carry data from one form to other

public partial class DialPad : Form
    {
        public MainGUI guiObject;

```
    public DialPad(MainGUI mG)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        guiObject = mG;
    }
```

Comment: Rough class information: use classes!  Seriously: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your point no. 2

> I have to make sure when user clicks
>   on the close 'x' , I have to log out
>   and close the windows?

In the event `FormClosing` of the form, take a look at e.ClosingReason.

So if user closes using Close Button (X), then ClosingReason would be UserClosing. So check that and then write appropriate code therein.

> How do I tranfer the control from one
>   form to another?

For e.g
If you want to get the number in main form from Dialpad form.

1st in the contructor of main form

```
public static MainForm instance = null;
public string numberInMainForm = null;
public MainForm()
{

instance = this;
}
```

now in your dialpad form, when user enters the number, you can pass the number (or any other variable.) to main form from the dialpad form directly.

In dialpad form just write:

```
MainForm.instance.numberInMainForm = number;
```

thats it. You are done !!

Comment: i was trying this without checking for the 'Closing reason' hence i was in trouble.. Now one of my point is clear..

Comment: I have 3 point unclear: as i told you in above question, I have a dial pad popping up when i click on call button just like a touch screen phone, the user dials the number(Clicks on the number buttons) and finally clicks call.. Now this dial pad should return the entered value to the main form.

Comment: I hope this works , if it does then it wil make my work easy :)

Comment: @Chandu: This surely works, we use this techniques in our projects.

Answer (score 3):

By the sounds of it your dialler form should be a dialog..

```
class MyDiallerDialog : Form
{
    public String DialledNumber
    {
        get { return this.txtNumber.Text; } // Or however the form stores its number...
    }
}

class MyMainForm : Form
{
    void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var dialog = new MyDiallerDialog())
        {
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                String number = dialog.DialledNumber;

                // do something interesting with the number...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - this is definitely the approach I would take. None of that static variables nonsense - that way lies madness.

Comment: @Erik @Matt If this is the way to carry variables then, how can i use the user credentials which i took in the LoginForm to MainForm. All the methods in the MainForm use user credentials to access the DB so i would need credentials to be sent to main form. The issue is when i close the loginform all the info is destroyed. I can access it right?

Comment: Forms are not data storage, they exist only to present/collect information from the user. Once that information has been collected - the forms responsibility is over. You need to think about how you are going to store that information in your application (not just in the forms).

Your MainForm needs a UserCredentials object to do its work - it doesn't neeed a LoginForm to be available at all times. Make UserCredentials a property on your main form, and then set the property in the same way I described above. At all times you should be thinking "what does this object require to do its work?"

Comment: @MattDavey Can you give me an example code for what you mentioned?

Comment: You could also edit the constructor for MainForm and have it require a UserCredentials object during construction. I presume you're creating your LoginForm in the 'program.cs' file? Probably via `Application.Run(new LoginForm());` - is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

let us assume you 1st form is **loginform**,
Suppose User press **OK** on the login form, so on 
`OK_click()` 
event call another form.
suppose your name of the another form is `MainForm.cs` then you can call using...

```
MainForm mf = new Mainform()
```

Suppose you want to close the **login form** when user press **OK**  of your **logIn** form you can keep the order in following way..

```
 private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       . . .
        // your validations
        //return bool  (true or false ) to confirm you have complted validations

        MainForm mf = new Mainform();
        mf.show();  //  or you can use  mf.ShowDialog();

        . . .

        . . .
        this.close();



    }
```

When you will close the `MainForm`,its control will come directly to the next line after `mf.show();`

To close any form use
`this.close()` command.

I hope this will help you ands you can start working on your project now.

**EDIT:**

Add  a new class file named `commondata.cs` and in that use **static variables** like

```
 public static string myString = "";
```

You can keep all the static functions and variables in the common file like `commonData.cs` so that you can modify its value from anywhere and can be used from anywhere.

Before closing your current form store the information in the **static myString** so even if u close the current form related information will be stored in `myString` & you can access it in any form using commonData.myString command.

```
string temp = commonData.myString;
```

Regards,

Sangram Nandkhile.

Comment: Here i am assuming that you know basics of C#:winforms and how to add forms and class file to project. It is not possible to give you entire project but this small approach will help you to understand how it will work...

Comment: Ya i know the basics of C#, my problem is when i close one form, i should have some information from the previous form to the next form? How do i do this? Once the old form is closed, it wil destroy all the info right?

Comment: @Sangram can u let me know if i can do the above mentioned?

Comment: Add new class file named commondata.cs and in that use static variables like **public static string myString**.Before closing your current form store the information in the static **myString** so even if u close the current form related information will be stored in **myString** & you can access it in any form using **commonData.myString** command.

Comment: @ Chandu: i have edited the answer so you can understand it . Please reply if u have any other query.

Comment: @ Sangram what i was using till date was hiding the form so that the information is not lost. Thanks this will save some memory and speed up my application.